# matplotlib making the same base for 2 functions

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am looking for a way to get the first and second graph to start from the same point. In this case, I would like the 'Pair price' to stay where it is (starting from 1.342), and for 'Analysis' start (which is 0) to be on the same level as start of 'Pair price'. So basically I'm looking to shift the right y-axis upwards.

Also, how could I call autofmt_xdate() in this code so that my x-axis is nicely formatted?

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

host = host_subplot(111)
par = host.twinx()

host.set_xlabel("Time")
host.set_ylabel("Pair Price")
par.set_ylabel("Analysis")

p1, = host.plot_date(np_price_data[-3000:-1000,1],np_price_data[-3000:-1000,0],'-',label='Pair Price')
p2, = par.plot_date(np_anlysis_data[:,1],np_analysis_data[:,0],'-',label='Analysis')

host.autoscale_view()
host.grid(True)

leg = plot.legend(loc='lower right')

host.yaxis.get_label().set_color(p1.get_color())
leg.texts[0].set_color(p1.get_color())

par.yaxis.get_label().set_color(p2.get_color())
leg.texts[1].set_color(p2.get_color())

plot.show()
```

[image: analysis graph]

Comment: 1) Use [``set_ylim()``](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylim) on ``host`` and ``par``. 2) What happens when you just call ``plot.autofmt_xdate()``? Do you get an error, nothing happens, the result is undesirable? Please elaborate.

Comment: There is an error saying "'module' object has no attribute 'autofmt_xdate'", and also eclipse is showing it as an error. Also, set_ylim() doesn't really do what I want. I don't want to just cut off the lower part of the right yscale, I want to move it up, so that the whole green graph starts at same point where 'Pair Price' is starting.

Comment: Can you reduce to a self-contained example that does not rely on your exact data?  Why don't you just use `twinx`?